# Smallest group for finite groups.

Tags: group-theory

Does it make sense to talk about a smallest group imaginable in terms of this group being unique? I know that given the prerequisites for a group (closure, identity, inverse, associativity) and if we don't necessarily require that the subgroup be a generator for the set I could construct a group for example: $\langle \mathbb{Z}_n, +\rangle$ for the smallest possible n, but would there not be other groups containing only 1 element? Also if we are dealing with non-finite groups what would be the possible smallest group imaginable?

(Sorry beforehand if this is poorly formulated as I have only recently started to learn about group theory.)

Comment: How can there be multiple groups with one element?  The one element is the identity element and the only possible operation is $e*e=e$.  Perhaps you are claiming the $<1,\times>$ and $<0,+>$ and $<Babar\ the\ elephant, looking\ in\ a\ mirror>$ are different *things* but, I'd say that the only thing that matters is the the structure and they all have the exact same structure:  the single element operated on itself results in the single element.

Comment: Well, $\mathbb Z,+$ is an infinite group and it's "small"ish.  But so is $\mathbb Z_2^\infty, +$ (where where each element is an infinite series of $0$s and $1$ and the operator is adding mod 2 every position).

Comment: Right so if the set I constructed contains a single element and it is also group then it follows from necessity that this is the identity element defined under the operation e*e? I understand the generalization of structure you mentioned. That cleared up the misunderstanding I was having. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course there's a group with a single element $\{e\}$ and it is unique up to isomorphism. The group operation is given by $(e,e)\mapsto e$, no other choice by the way. It is also known as the trivial group. And every group contains it as a subgroup.

Except for the trivial group every finite group has a minimal subgroup. Simply because finite groups have finitely many subgroups, and nontrival groups have at least $2$ subgroups.

Infinite groups on the other hand need not have minimal subgroups, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}$ has an infinite chain of descending groups, never ending, never stabilizng, i.e.

$$\mathbb{Z}\supseteq 2\mathbb{Z}\supseteq 4\mathbb{Z}\supseteq\cdots\supseteq 2^n\mathbb{Z}\supseteq\cdots$$

Comment: I assume "minimal" means "minimal nontrivial" (or "minimal among nontrivial")...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes, and the trivial group has no nontrivial subgroups.

Comment: An infinite group has a minimal nontrivial subgroup if and only if it has torsion. The only ones that don't have minimal nontrivial subgroups are the torsionfree groups (which includes the trivial group, as it is torsionfree).

Answer (score 2):

Note that for induction purposes (in case of finite groups) and classification, one is interested in deriving structure and properties of so-called minimal non-$\mathfrak{X}$ groups, where $\mathfrak{X}$ is a property of groups. This means that all proper subgroups of $G$ possess the property $\mathfrak{X}$, but $G$ itself not. For $\mathfrak{X}$ being abelian, Miller and Moreno classified these groups already in 1903, while later on, O.J. Schmidt did the same for $\mathfrak{X}$ being nilpotent. Minimal non-$M$ groups (monomial groups, a class between nilpotent and solvable) were treated late 1970ties by R.W. van der Waall (see for example [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/1385725880900128)).